# How to get the data I need from airbnb web page?

Tags: javascript, php, python

I want to get the dates booked and price from the the airbnb page: https://www.airbnb.com.sg/rooms/2781352 under the "Calendar" tab of it.

I am quite newbie to this, and I want to python to do that, can I?

And what else should learn, javascript, PHP?

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For extracting data from web pages, my first stop is [`Beautifulsoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). It is designed for just this purpose, and is excellent at it. Combine it with the great [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) HTTP library (so much better and easier than `urllib`/`urllib2`/etc.) for getting the pages.

Both of these are Python modules, there is no need to learn any other programming languages to do it, although it greatly helps to have an understanding of HTML and DTDs ([Document Type Definitions](http://www.w3schools.com/DTD/)) for setting up paths.